# How to send a very long messages with SmsManager

Tags: android, smsmanager

basiclly i have a chat application that i send sms messages between clients with the SmsManager but i to be able to send longer messages than it can.
I read that it can only send something about 40-60 letters but i want to sendm messages like 200-400 notes 
So is there a way to do it with it?

Comment: Ideally you should not send messages via SMS, use GCM instead.

Comment: Have you checked the ´divideMessage()´ and ´sendMultipartTextMessage()´ methods, as described in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html.